# Python 3.4 tkinter button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

My program should destroy `btn1` and create it again after one second in loop. I don't no why but my program only destroy `btn1` and don't show this again. Anyone have idea why?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def hide():
    btn1.destroy()
    btn1.after(2000,hide)

def show():
    btn1 = Button(root, bd=c, text="Hello\nWorld", relief="ridge", cursor="trek")
    btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    btn1.after(3000,show)

root = Tk()

root.geometry("350x150+400+400")

c=random.randint(20,40)

btn1 = Button(root, bd=c, text="Hello\nWorld", relief="ridge", cursor="trek")
btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)

btn1.after(2000,hide)
btn1.after(3000,show)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you use grid_forget instead of creating a new object each time.  Note that what happens at multiples of 6 seconds (2000 X 3000) depends on which one is the last one to execute.

```
def hide():
    btn1.grid_forget()
    btn1.after(2000,hide)

def show():
    btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    btn1.after(3000,show)

root = Tk()

root.geometry("350x150+400+400")

c=random.randint(20,40)

btn1 = Button(root, bd=c, text="Hello\nWorld",
              relief="ridge", cursor="trek")
btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)

btn1.after(2000,hide)
btn1.after(3000,show)

root.mainloop()
```